# Is it possible to save output.css to other folder

Tags: sass

Sample Directory

```
Root 
- Js   folder
- css folder
-Sass input folder
-input.scss
-Sass output folder
- compiled css folder
- php
```

I am newbie to sass, I know how to use 
`Sass --watch input.scss:output.css` to start the project

Is it possible to save output.css to other folder like sample above directory, i want to save to other folder name sass output folder

I tried this

```
Sass --watch input.scss: root/css/sass output/output.css
```

But I got an error.

Supposed to be like this

```
Root 
- Js   folder
- css folder
-Sass input folder
-input.scss
-Sass output folder
-output.css
- compiled css folder
- php
```

Comment: What error did you get?

Comment: i got error message "no such file or directory @ rb-sysopen -"

Answer (score 1):

You can change the folder using the method you suggested for example:

`sass --watch root/css/sass:root/css/output`

Will watch the files in `root/css/sass` and compile them to `root/css/output/`

Comment: Congrats, for reference the docs are here http://sass-lang.com/documentation/file.SASS_REFERENCE.html